# if php statement works I need to hide html tag

Tags: php

I have php condition like below

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
$categories = $product->getCategoryIds(); /*will return category ids array*/

$t = $categories[1];
$cat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($t);

if(strpos($cat->getName(), 'Bird Ring') !== FALSE){
    ?>
        <div>
            <button id="click-me">Pick Coordinates</button>
        </div>
    <?php
};

?>
```

if this function works I need to hide below tag

```
<b id="test" style="display:none;">errorrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</b>
```

It will be shown when I press button I dont want to show if this php function works

Please help me with this matter

Comment: what are your efforts??

Comment: There is no function. That is a simple if statement (a.k.a condition)

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. Either you want to not output that html snippet or mark it as hidden (by means of css maybe), then _do that._ Or you want to be able to dynamically toggle it by pressing some button, then you need some client side logic. That would be javascript, not php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check condition in style

```
<b id="test" style="<?php if(strpos($cat->getName(), 'Bird Ring') !== FALSE){echo 'display:none;'}?>">errorrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</b>
```

or you can use

```
$style=(strpos($cat->getName(), 'Bird Ring') !== FALSE)?'display:none;':'';
<b id="test" style="<?php echo $style; ?>">errorrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</b>
```